# Install Nginx with Ansible to target machine which does not have an internet connection

Tags: linux, nginx, ansible

The remote system is Ubuntu Server 16.04. It is connected to intranet environment but does not have an internet connection. How to install `Nginx` to such remote machine with `Ansible`?

Comment: If the target machine does not have a network connection, then how do you connect it?

Comment: Download the software i need to deploy on the control machine. The network environment is an intranet environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upload `nginx` [source file](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/install/#stable) to the remote machine if there is any connection in between
local machine, unarchive it and execute:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Need to execute something as follows with `Ansible` but further steps might be necessary:

```
- name: Upload nginx source file and unarchive
  unarchive:
    src: nginx-1.10.1.tar.gz
    dest: /tmp/nginx-1.10.1

- name: Build and install from source
  shell: ./configure && make && make install
  args:
    chdir: /tmp/nginx-1.10.1
  become: true
```